# Как добавлять в LocalStorage, но не перезаписывать данные?

Tags: javascript

Предыдущий вопрос про добавление в localStorage решился. Теперь не могу понять - как по щелчку кнопки добавлять каждый раз новую информацию в localStorage, а не перезаписывать старую, как сейчас получается. Не пойму в чём причина, уже неделю мучаюсь с этим.

```js
tdOne.innerHTML = (day + '.' + (month + Number(1)) + '.' + year);
  tdTwo.innerHTML = window.calc.income.value;
  tdThree.innerHTML = window.calc.expense.value;
  tdFour.innerHTML = window.calc.amount.value;
  tdFive.innerHTML = window.calc.result.textContent;

  let oneVal = tdOne.innerHTML;
  let twoVal = tdTwo.innerHTML;
  let threeVal = tdThree.innerHTML;
  let fourVal = tdFour.innerHTML;
  let fiveVal = tdFive.innerHTML;

  let makeNewRow = function (oneVal, twoVal, threeVal, fourVal, fiveVal) {
    let allRows = [];

    let addRow = {
      one: oneVal,
      two: twoVal,
      three: threeVal,
      four: fourVal,
      five: fiveVal,
    }

    allRows.push(addRow);

    localStorage.setItem('addedrow', JSON.stringify(allRows));
  }
    makeNewRow(oneVal, twoVal, threeVal, fourVal, fiveVal);
```

Comment: Оставьте в вопросе минимально необходимый код/html.

Comment: Оставил) HTML, кажется, вообще не нужен.

Comment: "минимально необходимый" - уберите из кода три из пяти клеток. Никого не интересует, что Вы в них выводите. Это уменьшит количество кода в вопросе примерно в два раза, соответственно, облегчит задачу отвечающим.

Comment: Что подразумевается под клеткой? Абзац с кодом?

Comment: Элементы `td` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let allRows = [];
// get what is already there
if (localStorage.getItem('addedrow'))
  allRows = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addedrow'));

let addRow = {
  one: oneVal,
  two: twoVal,
  three: threeVal,
  four: fourVal,
  five: fiveVal,
}

allRows.push(addRow);

localStorage.setItem('addedrow', JSON.stringify(allRows));
```

Answer (score 1):

в localStorage и должны сохранятся только данные после каждого обновления страница перерисовывается соответственно ты должен заполнять свой table значениями из localStorage если там есть что то или своими пример

```
innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('что то из хранилищя') || 'что то свое'
```

пример того как не заменять а добавлять то есть берешь старое значение и обеденяеш с новым

```
  localStorage.setItem('myKey',(localStorage.getItem('myKey') || '') + 'new value')
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой чёткий и понятный коммент. Всё получилось! Правда, пришлось поковыряться. Данные теперь автоматически подгружаются из localStorage после перезагрузки. Но появилась новая проблема - данные в localStorage добавляются и извлекаются только 1 раз! Соответственно, когда я ввожу новые данные, они не добавляются в localStorage к уже имеющимся, а замещают их. Подскажи - как решить проблему. Если что, код в данном примере остался прежним, замена произошла в другом файле (добавил getItem)/

Comment: @Sol-Mayers если добавить в обект много одинаковых ключей по твоему сколько  ключей будет в обекте... это и вопрос и ответ

Comment: @Sol-Mayers как подсказку нужно обеденить старое и новое значение а не перезаписивать

Comment: Посмотри, пожалуйста мою очередную попытку. Никак не могу понять - как же менять названия ключей каждый раз? Они же неизменные. Меняются только значения этих ключей.

Comment: @Sol-Mayers обновил ответ

Comment: Благодарю! Мне это сильно помогло! Тут, вроде и учебник читаешь и статьи смотришь. А додуматься всё равно не можешь)

Comment: @Sol-Mayers не за что это приходит со временем и ключи тоже меняются просто ты старый заменяеш таким же новым вот и кажется что не меняеш